# how can i generate mysql lock timeout error on my server?

Tags: mysql, locking, timeout

My mysql server gives me sometimes such errors (i see them in logs) and i have a clue what is causing this
now to check this i need to make such situation by myself(and later, when i fix my app, test it again, to make sure it does not happen anymore)

what is the best way to generate mysql lock timeout error? what should be changed in my.cnf, and how should i use mysqlslap then? (as for now i only managed to get "too many connections " error messages in shell :) btw - it is bash on centos, mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.66

help me people!

Answer (score 0):

### SUGGESTION #1

Assuming your data uses the InnoDB storage engine, you need to configure [**innodb_lock_wait_time**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_lock_wait_timeout) It's default value is 50 seconds.

You could lower it at your discretion. Perhaps to something ridiculously low (like 1)

### SUGGESTION #2

If you have [innodb_file_per_table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table) enabled, you can also choke the number of open files with [**innodb_open_files**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_open_files)

### SUGGESTION #3

I recommend you create a test script that will deliberately update the same row dozens (or even hundreds) of times. Then, have mysqlslap launch that script hundreds of times.

Comment: Thanks Rolando
Tried innodb_lock_wait_time=1 so far - it doesn't give timeout lock error...also tried mysql update from bash shell in loop - still the same :(
tomorrow will try 
SUGGESTION #2

Comment: innodb_file_per_table is disabled
tried mysqlslap and loops in bash - with no luck